# TextView: Which Character/Span clicked?

Tags: android, textview, clicklistener

Is it possible to detect which character on a Spanned TextView is clicked *without* declaration of onClickListeners on Spans?
I need a mechanism that when a textView clicked, detects location of click on TextView (e.g. a function whcih returns 17th character at textView clicked), then I can extract if an special span is located there or not.
Currently i can detect which span clicked by defining ClickListeners on them however this soultion is not handy for my special usage in application.

Comment: you can use View.OnTouchListener to get the touch point of your TextView

Comment: that way you dont need any span at all

Comment: if you are no longer interested in your question just close it so poeple wont waste their time answering it

Comment: I did not find any intresting answer yet answer still waiting for an answer